# Is there a cost to query an Amazon Redshift Server?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an amazon redshift server deployed for my company's website. If I heavily query the database to do operations on terabytes of data and send smaller amounts back, is there an additional cost above the $.25/hr/node?

Specifically, is there a cost associated with either the complexity of query or the compute time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With RedShift ([pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/pricing/)) you pay for the servers, not per query. Standard EC2 / VPC bandwidth prices may also apply.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that I have an unlimited bandwidth for data going out of the redshift cluster?

Comment: The RedShift pricing page doesn't mention bandwidth, except if you're pulling data from S3. Nothing I can find talks about RedShift bandwidth pricing. If you want definitive information you'll need to contact AWS.